# Slick Slider not working while loading ajax html to slides

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Inside .pricing-slide html code loading but slick-sliding not working. On static data it is working fine. Is there any other way to print ajax json data to view? I want to load the json data to codeigniter view.

````
<script>
    function viewPlan() {
     var mobile = $("#phone").val();
     var operator = $("#operator :selected").attr("id");
   var params = {phone: mobile, op_id: operator}
        console.log(mobile);
        console.log(operator);
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://www.bikashpay.online/roffer',
                data: params,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $.each( JSON.parse(data), function( key, value ) {
                       var price = value.price;
                       var offer = value.ofrtext;
                       var validity = value.validity;
                      // console.log(price);
                      
                 var html = '<div class= "mb-3">';
                     html +=   '<div class="pr-card pr-card-2">';
                     html +=      '<div class="pr-header">';
                     html +=        '<h4 class="heading">Business</h4>';
                     html +=      '</div>';
                     html +=      '<div class="pr-body">';
                     html +=        '<span class="bg-yellow">₹'+price+ '<span>/ '+validity+' Days</span></span>';
                     html +=         '<p>'+offer+'</p>';
                     html +=       '</div>';
                     html +=       '<div class="pr-footer">';
                     html +=         '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-round">Select Plan</a>';
                     html +=         '<div class="circle bg-yellow"></div>';
                     html +=       '</div>';
                     html +=     '</div>';
                     html +=   '</div>';

                     $(".pricing-slide").append(html);

                    });
                    

                }
            });
    }


    </script>```


Inside .pricing-slide html code loading but slick-sliding not working. On static data it is working fine. Is there any other way to print ajax json data to view?
Inside .pricing-slide html code loading but slick-sliding not working. On static data it is working fine. Is there any other way to print ajax json data to view?
````

Comment: The new HTML is getting loaded into the DOM after the slick slider script is already loaded, share how you are initiating the script, https://www.npmjs.com/package/slick-slider should you wrap new element in $('.your-element').slick('slickAdd',"<div></div>");